# Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou com um dúvida em relação a um array. Tenho a seguinte informação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que não estou conseguindo é percorrer o outro array. Segue abaixo o código.

```
 foreach ($file_contents->retorno->contatos as $contatos) {
echo "{$contatos->contato->codigo} - {$contatos->contato->nome} - ";
foreach ($contatos->contato->tiposContato as $contato) {
    dd($contato->tipoContato->descricao);
}
echo '<br>';
 }
```

Quando coloco o **dd** ele funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao imprimir com **echo** ele da erro.

```
foreach ($file_contents->retorno->contatos as $contatos) {
echo "{$contatos->contato->codigo} - {$contatos->contato->nome} - ";
foreach ($contatos->contato->tiposContato as $contato) {
    echo $contato->tipoContato->descricao;
}
echo '<br>';
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione `if(!isset($contatos->contato->tiposContato)){ dd($contatos->contato); }` na primeira linha do seu segundo `foreach` para verificar em qual dado está o erro

Comment: @ErlonCharles, Adicionei o if dentro do segundo foreach, mas continua dando o seguinte erro Undefined property: stdClass::$tiposContato

Comment: coloca antes do foreach

Answer (score 1):

Antes de tudo, te recomendo usar o `foreach` ao invés de um `for()` para iterar um array. (*mesmo que perca um pouco desempenho, deixa a leitura muito mais fácil*)

Existe a possibilidade de algum dos dados dentro do seu `$file_contents->retorno->contatos` não ter a propriedade `tiposContato`, sendo assim, recomendo utilizar um `isset()` para imprimir a propriedade apenas caso ela exista.

```
foreach ($file_contents->retorno->contatos as $contatos) {
    echo "{$contatos->contato->codigo} - {$contatos->contato->nome} - ";

    if(isset($contatos->contato->tiposContato)){
        foreach ($contatos->contato->tiposContato as $contato) {
            echo isset($contato->tipoContato) ? $contato->tipoContato->descricao) : false;
        }
    }

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Para verificar em que ponto a inconsistência pode estar acontecendo você pode dar um `dd()` condicional

```
if(!isset($contatos->contato->tiposContato)){
    dd($contatos->contato);
}
```

Comment: Boa Tarde Erlon,
Fiz as alterações como tu sugeriu, mas mesmo assim, não mostra o segundo array. Sempre cai no false.

Comment: Acho que o segundo `foreach` seria em `$contatos->tipoContato` já que tipo contato é um `array`.

Comment: Boa tarde Kayo, Ja fiz isso, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: @shadow, como eu disse, muito provavelmente algum dos dados não possui `tipoContato`, quando você usa o `dd()` ele para na primeira iteração do array, que provavelmente é um elemento que possui `tipoContato`, então ele funciona, mas se um elemento no meio do *array* não possui, ele vai parar e gerar o erro nesse ponto.

Comment: @ErlonCharles, eu fiz aquela validação que tu sugeriu, mas ele sempre cai no false. Não imprime nada

Comment: @shadow adicionei uma verificação com um `dd()` assim você vai poder entender o que está acontecendo para não exibir o dado que você precisa

Comment: @ErlonCharles, com essa verificação da o mesmo erro, Undefined property: stdClass::$tiposContato

Comment: Aaaaaa, então o erro está antes, vou editar a resposta